# PAM: how do I change someone else's password?

Tags: c, linux, authentication, pam, change-password

What PAM call do I have to make to reset a user's password?  I cannot figure it out.

Background:

I'm working on an embedded linux device.  Customers install this device, and create user accounts.  If one of those secondary user accounts gets locked out, or if a user forgets their password, we need a way where user #1 can reset the password for user #2.  Our conversion to PAM is new, I'm in the middle of switching over to it now.  Here are the calls I make to authenticate users:

```
pam_start();
pam_authenticate();
pam_acct_mgmt();
pam_end();
```

I see `pam_chauthtok()` for changing my own password, what I don't understand is if -- or how? -- I can use it or another similar call to assign a new password to another user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of having separate users is that they cannot do things like change each other's password. In order to change a user's password with PAM, you need to become that user. The easiest way to do this is to have a setuid-root binary, or a daemon that runs as root, which calls `setuid`, etc. to become the desired user then performs the operations to change password.

Of course this exposes your entire system to a great deal of risk, especially if you're not already skilled in these matters (which is clear from your question), so I'd think twice about whether this feature is necessary, and if so, whether you should hire an expert to handle it.

Comment: I'd like to learn how to make the right calls myself, so "hiring an expert to handle it" isn't the direction I want to go.  Tonight I tried calling pam_authenticate() and pam_acct_mgmt() to authenticate as root (this daemon runs as root), then seteuid() to the user for which I want to set the password, but this didn't work, pam_chauthtok() sends back rc=20: Authentication token manipulation error.  If you know how to use PAM to assign a password to a user account that was just created, then please share.

Comment: When the user is created, it is created without a password.  The password field in /etc/shadow is "*".  So if I wanted to authenticate as this brand-new user, what password would I use?  This is why I had assumed I had to authenticate as "root" -- a user I do control, and I since I logged in as root I know my password -- before I could attempt to change the password for a different user.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to authenticate the user. I looked at the PAM documentation a bit, and it should be sufficient to call `pam_start` with the desired user name and `pam_chauthtok` while running setuid-root...

Comment: That last comment was key for me.  I thought I always had to authenticate first.  Calling `pam_start()` with the username instead of NULL, and then skipping immediately to `pam_chauthtok()` worked like a charm.  Thank you.  Just out of curiosity, what documentation were you looking at?

Comment: I just googled "`man pam_chauthtok`" and then followed the link to the man page for `pam_start`.

Comment: Does not work for me. I setuid flag on my executable, and calling pam_start("passwd", "useridofanotheruser", &conv, &pamh); followed by pam_chauthtok(&pamh, 0);  and in the conv callback I see it asking for the current password for the user.  Providing blank or null fails with rc=20;